# .NET MVC Db Context Model Extension

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

What i want to do is fairly simple, although i don't get why i get an internal server error.

I am using Entity Framework with Database first approach.
I have a model Client corresponding to a database Table, declared also in the DbContext.

Then i want to generate a Client model with an additional property, so i am just extending the Client Model.

```
Client
--id
--name
--lastName

ClientDetails: Client
--IEnumerable<addresses>
```

Then i just cast the object inside a method

```
ClientDetails tempClient = (ClientDetails) repository.getClient(id);
```

Although Intelisence does not report an error, i get an internal server error when i am running the function.

I made several changes like duplicating the model not extending it, casting manually or using the Parent model in another function (This also returns an error)

And i came into the conclusion that when the Parent model is extended by another model , everything using that parent model or children "fails".
Is there any rule that Db.Context Models Cannot be extended even for external use?

Comment: (1) When you say internal server error, you're just telling us that IIS gives, you should find out what the actual exception is, edit your question and put it in there. (2) Maybe the error you're getting is a SQL Server permission error, this is a guess but it usually happens with you use code first.

Comment: Well it begins from the SQL library ending in the Json Parser exception. But i don't get it, when i don't extend the class everything works fine! After all i am working only with the parent class, i am not changing anything on the parent class! I am just extending it , and i am not using that other child class at all!! And again i get the Error.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the Client class partial?

An other option is to change the client class and add a property with the NotMapped attribute:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583

It is not a good idea to change generated code, but you could make your own Client class.

Don't use inheritance just to extend an EF class with a property you only need in your code and not in your database. 
Here is information if you need inheritance in your data:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

If you don't want to change the client class, you could also wrap it in an other class.

Comment: I am not Using Generated code. I wrote the classes my self. Why i just can't extend the client class?

Comment: have you tried adding a property with the NotMapped attribute in the client class?

Comment: Haven't tried that, because there will be many cases that i am going to need extra properties, and this will result in a very dirty coded model.But i will keep it as a backup solution